# Asp.net MVC 3 HttpContext.Current.Session null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, reportviewer

I am working on Asp.net Mvc3 application and using custom authentication using `IPrinciple`, IIdentity
and storing the authenicated user details in `HttpContext.Current.Session` (`SimpleSessinPessister` staic class).
 After navigating between diffrent actions /views (in same controller) (using RedirectToAction) `HttpContext.Current.Session` becomes null.

Another observation is that soon We generate PDF using `miscrosoft.reportviewer` this `HttpContext.Current.Session` becomes null and application is forced to relogin.

If `HttpContext.Current.Session becomes null then TempData is also becomes null ?

Thanks in advance. Jms

Comment: Are you recompiling in between? Since the Session is stored in-memory, if you recompile your application in VS data will be lost. The same could happen of course on your live server if IIS decides to recycle the application pool (which could happen at any time). That's why it is very bad to rely on ASP.NET Session.

Comment: need some code around your pdf generation and your static class

Comment: Thanks Darin, No I am not recompiling in between. As IIS can recycle the application pool anytime what is correct approch/to store Authenticated user details? Please provide more information on this. Thanks in advance . Jms

Comment: Code around PDF 
[Authorize]
public ActionResult PDFReport()
{ byte[] renderedBytes;                    
string PfdFileName = String.Format("P_{0}.pdf", DateTime.Now.ToString("s"));
 //Render the report
 renderedBytes = localReport.Render(
reportType,deviceInfo,out mimeType,out encoding,out fileNameExtension,out streams,         out warnings);
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + PfdFileName); //fileNameExtension);
TempData["Input"] = model;
return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
}

Comment: <pre> <code>Static class

public static class SessionPersister 
{
    public static string usernameSessionVar = "username";
public static string UserName
    {        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current == null) return string.Empty;

            var sessionVar =
                HttpContext.Current.Session[usernameSessionVar ];
            if (sessionVar != null)
                return sessionVar as string;
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[usernameSessionVar ] = value;
        }
    }
} </code> </pre>

Comment: @user2226680 - do not add code in comments like that, edit your question to include the code instead.

Comment: @user2226680 - I don't see why you need to store the authentication information in Session if you are also using IPrincipal and IIdentity.  Those already store your authentication information.